# biblatex-ieee and supra note

Tags: biblatex, ieeetran

I know this is sort of short notice (I'd posted a similar cry for help at [LaTeX Community](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=13034&p=49856#p49856)), but I have a thesis due Monday and the one thing standing between me and being ready (layout-wise) is this: I'm using `biblatex` with a slightly tweaked `biblatex-ieee` style (maybe not ideal but my thesis director had very specific directions and that was the closest) which I call with:

```
\usepackage[bibstyle=ieee,citestyle=authoryear,backref=false,hyperref=false]{biblatex}
```

But the problem is I need to replace already referenced items with "supra note". For example, if Belloni is referred to in footnote (`\footfullcite`) 17 as:

> `17.` R. Belloni, « The tragedy of Darfur and the limits of the ‘responsibility to protect’ », Ethnopolitics, vol. 5, no 4, nov. 2006, pp. 327–346.

I would like future references to the same author and article to look like (say in footnote 24, where I specify a page of the article):

> `24.` R. Belloni, supra note 17, p. 336.

Any idea?

Thanks a lot in advance!

PS: It actually seems like the "citestyle" can be removed or modified without any change. I guess that is itself isn't normal...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `citestyle=verbose-note` plus the following modifications.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[bibstyle=ieee,citestyle=verbose-note,firstinits=true]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  seenote = {supra note},
}

% Print first name of authors in follow-up notes
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{footcite:note}{%
  \ifnameundef{labelname}
    {\printfield{label}}
%     {\printnames{labelname}}% DELETED
    {\DeclareNameAlias{labelname}{default}% NEW
     \printnames{labelname}}% NEW
  \ifsingletitle
    {}
    {\setunit*{\nametitledelim}%
     \printfield[title]{labeltitle}}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printtext{%
    \bibstring{seenote}\addnbspace
    \ref{cbx@\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}%
    \iftoggle{cbx:pageref}
      {\ifsamepage{\the\value{instcount}}
                  {\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}
         {}
     {\addcomma\space\bibstring{page}\addnbspace
      \pageref{cbx@\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}}}
      {}}}
\makeatother

% AS A MEASURE OF LAST RESORT, assign the functions of \autocite to \footfullcite
%     (The correct way is to replace every instance of "\footfullcite"  in the text
%     with "\autocite")
\let\footfullcite\autocite

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Bel06,
  author = {Belloni, Roberto},
  year = {2006},
  title = {The tragedy of Darfur and the limits of the `responsibility to protect'},
  journaltitle = {Ethnopolitics},
  volume = {5},
  number = {4},
  pages = {327--346},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text \footfullcite{Bel06}.

Some text \footfullcite[336]{Bel06}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

(The filecontents environment is only used to include some external files directly into the example, so that it compiles. It is not necessary for the solution.)

EDIT: After a lot of comments, here's the code to the OP's last-minute request:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\smartcite}[\iffootnote\relax\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \iffootnote
     {\usebibmacro{footcite}}
     {\usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}
```

Comment: Excellent: I was thinking of looking at this tomorrow, but now I don't have to :-)

Comment: @Drounal: You're welcome! Feel free to register at tex.sx and accept my answer. ;-)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help lockstep!

Ok, so I copied your code at the appropriate place (I have multiple files but it seemed at its place with the rest of the "\usepackage" commands).

Unfortunately, I have quite a few of these when compiling:

LaTeX Warning: Reference `cbx@' on page 6 undefined on input line 57.

And the result looks like:

19. A. Ousman, cf. note ??, p. 102.

And I still have footnote reference to the same article one after the other...

PS: Joe? You're everywhere!

Comment: Ok, "cf." is now successfully replaced with "supra note" (I'm using french and not english) but the rest still doesn't work.

Comment: @Drounal: a) I added `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` to the part of my code that slightly modifies follow-up notes. b) Does your thesis compile without warnings/errors if you just change the citestyle to `verbose-note` and add `\let\footfullcite\autocite`? These are the most important modifications.

Comment: @Drounal: One more thing: After you add these modifications, remove all auxiliary files and then (!) try to compile.

Comment: Changing just citestyle to verbose-note doesn't seem to change anything at all. So no warnings there. But the aforementioned warning appear with \let\footfullcite\autocite. And when I top it all up with the rest of the code and the \makeatletter and \makeatother, the whole thing crashes down with "! Use of \@ doesn't match its definition" right from the beginning (\maketitle).

Comment: @Drounal: But my example works if you compile it as-is (with a new `.tex` file? If so: *In a copy* of your thesis, apply my modifications *without* `\let\footfullcite\autocite`. Replace every instance of `\footfullcite` with `\autocite` in, say, chapter 1. Then remove all other chapters. Does the resulting file compile without errors?

Comment: @Lockstep: I copied my thesis, simplified it, changed all \footfullcite with \autocite but to no avail. It compiles with the warnings (and therefore results in "??") without the code itself but stops short of compiling whenever the code is added. It seems to stems from the \makeat... commands. What do those do?

Comment: @Lockstep: If that's any help in figuring out what's weird, I'm using a modified version of the Cambridge thesis template available here: http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/textprocessing/ThesisStyle/

Comment: @Drounal: You *did* put those redefinitions before `\begin{document}`, didn't you? You may also leave them out for now and try again. And please test your "simplified" thesis with a) the *unmodified* `ieee` bibstyle b) with `bibstyle=verbose-note`. What are the results?

Comment: Wait, I simplified again and it's part working, that's weird. For some entries, it works just fine ; for some, I still have the "??" instead of the previous note number ; and for others, I have the name of the author, the name of the article and the "supra note"... And all that wihtout the code, just the "citestyle=verbose-note,firstinits=true" and string definition.

Comment: PS: yes, they're definied in a class file so it's called properly, before the \begin{document}

Comment: @Drounal: My guess is that the name of the article will be shown if there are several bibentries from the same author.

Comment: @Drounal: The "defined in a class file" is very important information. In this case, REMOVE `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

Comment: Well, it seems to be working in the simplified copy of the thesis, even without the main part of the code...

Comment: There's just one that it won't work for...

Comment: @Drounal: That's not the main part -- it just adds the first name of authors to follow-up citations. I suggest to forget it for now. Instead, apply the code version that seems to be working to a new (and exact!) copy of your thesis, replace every `\footfullcite` with `\autocite` and compile. If it works, skim over a bunch of citations for anything out of order. You're on the right track!

Comment: If it's working for all but one citation, please provide a compilable example that contains just this citation.

Comment: Ok, now I have the full copy of the thesis, using: \usepackage[bibstyle=ieee,backref=false,hyperref=false,citestyle=verbose-note,firstinits=true]{biblatex} and the redefinitions. And most of it work. But I resumed getting the LaTeX Warning: Reference `cbx@' on page 9 undefined on input line 73. and sometimes I'll have "??" instead of the supra note number. I haven't checked the numbers but it would seem like the warning matches the question marks.

Comment: A bunch of them aren't working but I can't find a pattern: sometimes they're articles, sometimes not... Also, I'm using BibDesk so I'm not typing the bibliography by hand.

Comment: Trick question : what happens to the \fullcite that I use in \footnote?

Comment: Spoiler alert : the warnings do match the "??" indeed.

Comment: Again: If most of the citations are displayed correctly, there must something special about the ones that aren't. Trim your working copy until nothing but the "bad" citations remain in the text. Either you find out the cause of the "bad" behaviour in the process, or you'll end with a compilable example that shows the problem and that I can experiment with.

Comment: I get it!! The ones that don't work are the ones that have previously been called as \fullcite and not \autocite (formerly \footfullcite). I knew there was something fishy about those \fullcite!

Comment: Regarding your "trick question": Since biblatex v1.3, `\autocite` is smart enough not to try to typeset footnotes inside footnotes. Speaking of it: a) Are the "bad" citations in footnotes? b) are you using the latest biblatex version?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, maybe I wasn't so clear about this. The backend bibliography is perfectly fine, everything shows up. Wonderful. My entire concern is for references in footnotes. Most of them are (were) using \footfullcite (now gone) but others are included in footnotes (like \footnote{For more details, see: \fullcite{blabal}}). So I should change all my \fullcite to \autocite as well? And, yes, I pretty have the latest version of everything. That's been needed to fix other issues.

Comment: @Drounal: Certain information bits would have been helpful at the start. On the other hand, you're getting a "thesis is due Monday" benefit. ;-) And yes, change every `\fullcite` inside footnotes to `\autocite`.

Comment: Fantastic! Sorry about the missing information, I should have realised that way before. I guess I'm so into the code that I forget not everyone is... Thanks a lot for your help, that was a terrific job you did!

Comment: Just registered and looking for the accept button.

Comment: Silly me. I found it.

Comment: PS: I won't forget you and Joseph and a few others in the 'acknowledgement' section of my thesis :)

Comment: @Lockstep: last minute issue with \autocite. Now that I've replaced my "\footnote{Blabla. Cf.\fullcite{bla}}" with "\footnote{Blabla. Cf.\autocite{bla}}", I have the "bla" part between parenthesis, which is most unwelcome. Any idea?

Comment: @Drounal: As a quick fix, write `\footnote{\renewcommand*{\bibleftparen}{}\renewcommand*{\bibrightparen}{}Blabla. Cf. \autocite{bla}.}`. (Sorry for not providing a general solution.)

Comment: Thanks! But... hmmm... I have to write that *every* time I have this scenario? That's probably around 50 or 60 times....

Comment: On second thought, bad idea. Instead, add the following at the end of your preamble: `\let\origfootnote\footnote\renewcommand*{\footnote}[1]{\origfootnote{\renewcommand*{\bibleftparen}{}\renewcommand*{\bibrightparen}{}#1}}` This is still only a workaround.

Comment: A better solution: Add the following to your preamble: `\DeclareCiteCommand{\smartcite}[\iffootnote\relax\mkbibfootnote]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \iffootnote
     {\usebibmacro{footcite}}
     {\usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}` (I replaced `\mkbibparens` with `\relax`.)

Comment: OK. Two questions: 1) I'm puzzled by the '%' in mid line, since it comments the rest of the line. Normal? 2) Then should I replace my "\autocite" with "\smartcite"? All of them? Even the former "\footfullcite"?

Comment: Ad 1): I edited my original answer instead of trying to put a bunch of code into a comment. 2) No. Leave everything else alone.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for the details. Although I do maintain that the '%' should be removed since, if you copy-paste from your message, it will half the command and leave the "\usebibmacro{citeindex}" part unclosed.

Comment: @Drounal Leave the '%' in, but force a new line right after it. (In this case it's probably not necessary, but sometimes % characters are used at the ends of lines to avoid unwanted spaces in command definitions.)

Comment: @Lockstep: Any chance we tweak the solution in order to add "ibid" and "ibidem" when appropriate? Or would that be too great a challenge?

Comment: Untested: Replace `citestyle=verbose-note` with `citestyle=verbose-inote`.